# Copy values one MySQL column to another, but formatted

Tags: mysql, date, copy

I have added a DATE column to a table, but now need to populate that DATE column with the values from another column - except that original column is an INT.  The INT column is mmddyyyy.  Is there a way to copy and format using

```
UPDATE `table` SET int_column = date_column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using str_to_date and lpad functions:

```
UPDATE `table` SET date_column = str_to_date(lpad(int_column, 8, 0),'%m%d%Y')
```

---

Why used `lpad(int_column, 8, 0)` - When date is, say, 02012017, the direct cast to char will convert it into 2012017, for which str_to_date function will return null. Lpad pads required 0 to make length 8 and hence outputs 02012017 which str_to_date function will correctly convert.